# Postgres max value per hour with time it occurred

Tags: postgresql

Given a Postgres table with columns highwater_datetime::timestamp and highwater::integer, I am trying to construct a select statement for a given highwater_datetime range, that generates rows with a column for the max highwater for each hour (first occurrence when dups) and another column showing the highwater_datetime when it occurred (truncated to the minute and order by highwater_datetime asc).  e.g.

```
| highwater_datetime | max_highwater |
+--------------------+---------------+
| 2021-01-27 20:05   |             8 |
| 2021-01-27 21:00   |             7 |
| 2021-01-27 22:00   |             7 |
| 2021-01-27 23:00   |             7 |
| 2021-01-28 00:00   |             7 |
| 2021-01-28 01:32   |             7 |
| 2021-01-28 02:00   |             7 |
| 2021-01-28 03:00   |             7 |
| 2021-01-28 04:22   |             9 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DISTINCT ON` should do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('hour', highwater_datetime))
       highwater_datetime,
       highwater
FROM mytable
ORDER BY date_trunc('hour', highwater_datetime),
         highwater DESC,
         highwater_datetime;
```

`DISTINCT ON` will output the first row for each entry with the same hour according to the `ORDER BY` clause.